# Ajax Request for same domain only. Restrict Cross domain ajax

Tags: ajax, dns

I am new for jquery with limited knowledge.
I am doing ajax request to fetch much imp  information to display into the page without reloading the page.
It is done.
But i am worried about. Any can do the call from other server to that php file to get information details.

My Question is that How i can restrict the others to access that file using ajax or directly putting the file path in browser address bar?

Please Help in it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

An ajax request is like any other http request.So you can add the security layer on your server using session-cookies, which will work only if user is logged-in(or you can create dummy sessions for pages that don't expect user to be logged in)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to include a CSRF token in all your AJAX calls. This prevents CSRF attacks since the attacker cannot put the right token in its submissions.